# TFS pivot table?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, wiql

Is it possible to make a pivot table or join linked items IDs in one field?
For example I have 2 top level workitems (let their ids are: 100 and 200) with there childs (101,102,103 and 201,202):

```
100
-101
-102
-103
200
-201
-202
```

I want to create some query that return me something like this:

```
100 - 101,102,103
200 - 201,202
```

or at least:

```
101 - 100
102 - 100
103 - 100
201 - 200
202 - 200
```

Comment: You can use a "work item and direct links" query and it will give you something like you first table.

Comment: that is the first table. I am interesting in how make it looks like second one

Comment: Nothing in the product, you'll have to write your own script.  You can do it with PowerShell and the REST API.  Let me know if you need help with that.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way inside Azure DevOps / TFS to do this.

However, you could use a tree query inside TFS and the TFS-Excel plugin. The default output looks like this:
[image]

`Title 2` is the child of the predescessing `Title 1`. Same with `Title 3`. By using some formulas, it should be possible to create a propper table.

Comment: well, thank you for your answer, first of all! It's a pity that there is no way inside Azure DevOps / TFS to do this :(
Excel looks inconvenient because I want to share my pivot table across a few people to look at any moment. Query in TFS seems a best way